# MVC with Article Web Site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a Web site that will have a lot of articles. I created a ArticleController for the Web site. As an example, the first article to be implemented is Machine Language. So I created a view called machine_language.cshtml.

```
    public class ArticleController : Controller
{
    // GET: Article
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Machine_Language()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

So far in the controller I have to code above.

So my question is, I have 500 articles that need to be converted to start with. Normally, I created an ASPX page for each article, but now I am creating a view, since I am using MVC.

So does that mean I will need to have 500+ ActionResults in the ArticleController? One for each view/article.

Before I get started I want to make sure I'm doing this correctly, because it seems rather strange. If I have to create an action result with each article's name. I will end up having a huge ArticleController. Once there are a couple thousand articles, things will get seriously out of control.

**Edit:** P.S. I like to use pages for the articles. Since they are static content. I am trying to stay away from having huge articles with images, videos, etc... in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you retrieving "article data/text"?  In this particular situation, I'd have a View Model that has `ArticleText` as a property, and then you might need other article-specific items (tags?  Author(s)?  etc.).

Then pass this View Model from your controller's action to the view.  The view would then be in charge of rendering this particular article to the user.

With this particular design, you'd have a **single action** in a **single controller** passing data (a single view model) to a **single view**.

In my opinion, that is the most scalable and the best approach.

Step away from the web forms thought where a single "viewing experience" equals on a "single entity" in the backend.  That's the beauty and power (and scalability) of MVC.

Comment: I had intended to just create a view for each article. I was going to place the article text/HTML in the view. I did want to have a Category feature, where a person could click on a specific category and it would show all articles in that category. I have some ideas of how to do that. I also want each article to have a GUID because I might decide to use article comments in the future. So the comments will go into a database, but the articles will still be pages. I like your idea, but I am new to MVC. Do you have a code example of what you mean?

Comment: @Choatech I don't have anything available at this moment, but I think this would be a good place to start: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/575397/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-ASP-NET-MVC-for Once you get the idea of ASP.NET MVC then let us know if you have any specific questions about the implementation.

Comment: @Choatech Probably a very idea to have one action result per article. Instead, store the articles in the database, and use one action result to retrieve the desired article.

Comment: So I will use a combination of both. I will try to add a single view model and I guess I will move the article text into a database. That way, I can assign a primary key to each article which will help with comments and other functions I add in the future.